# Instantiate Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL's DbContext directly

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have created an EF Core DbContext using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL. I would like to instantiate this DbContext inside a test case in a unit test project. Not to create an actual unit test, but to experiment manipulating a postgresql database using this DbContext.

Since this is not an ASP.NET Core project, there is no dependency injection nor AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql / AddDbContext extension methods.

I have checked the [documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html), couldn't find an example to do so.

So, how do I instantiate this DbContext directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the `UseNpgsql` extension method can be used here:

```
using Xunit;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyTestProject
{
    public class DbContextTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ActualQuery()
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseNpgsql("Host=mypgsvr;Database=mydb;Username=myusr;Password=mypass");
            var SUT = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

            var firstRow = SUT.mytable.First();

            Assert.NotNull(firstRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to simply have a constructor on your DbContext that accepts a connection string, or a parameterless constructor and perform connection string lookup internally (e.g. via Microsoft.Extension.Configuration). Using DbContextOptionsBuilder is needlessly heavy for this use.

See [the EF Core docs for regular .NET Core applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite), as opposed to ASP.NET applications which typically use dependency injection.

Comment: Wow the man himself! :) BTW thanks for Npgsql. I'd rather not change the DbContext's constructor because I do use it in an asp.net core app with dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :) It should be fine to have both constructors - one for ASP.NET and one for testing - but it's also fine to build your options as you've proposed.